# How to create dynamic sql inline statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, dynamicquery

I am creating advance search facility in one of my application. In that functionality i have to store selected search criteria. My search result is based on Logi XML...Logi XML requires SQL inline statement so that reason i have to store sql inline query into database table.

I have below tables in my current database.

```
Employee            Salary             PresentInfo
ID                   ID                    ID
Name                EMPID                 SalaryID
City                Basic                 TotalDays
State               HRA                   PresentDays  
Zip                 PF
Phone               DA
```

Now user can select any criteria from above tables. I am managing selected criteria into session context. I mean to say i have all the selected details by user. I want to create dynamic sql inline statement in business logic with respective joins.

below function in business logic class

```
public string GetDetails(List<Class1> Entity)
{
     //What should I write here? I have all the data in entity class
}
```

So if anyone have any idea about this scenario than please help me in this.
Thanxs in Advance.

Comment: What does your `GetDetails` functions returns? It can not be `void` isn't it?

Comment: @nvrtheless: Sorry it's return type will be as string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very brief 3 points you can start with [I am assuming you want employee records for a given id]:

```
public Employee GetEmployeeDetails(int employeeId)
{
    //Create a connection to the data source

    //Query against datasource and get the result to a Employee with given employeeId

    //get the result and assing values to an employee instance

    //return employee
}
```

Comment: No man you are not getting my question well. I need sql query like select statement which saves in database table. I mean i want to store search result and user can see again...Thats it..

Comment: Soething like this? `INSERT INTO Queries (SELECT e.id FROM Employee e)` For this you need to have table called **Queries**

Comment: No dear you are not getting my point...have u any communication site account like gmail??